# numpy indexing mixed tuple-index and range-index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a numpy array a with shape (m,n,3) that I want to index into the first two columns with another array idx of shape (100,2). So what I want is the following:

```
np.array([a[x,y,:] for x,y in idx])
```

What's the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Try `a[idx[:,0], idx[:,1], :]`.  That is, use the whole columns of `idx` as the first and second indices.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! If you make it into an answer then I can accept.